# How to get the src of all images within a ul using xpath

Tags: php, html, xpath, web-scraping

I need to find the src of all the images that falls under this ul. I am using xpath to do it. But it returns the src of only first image. How to get all src ? Here is my HTML structure.

```
<ul id="product-slider">
  <li >
    <img src="1.jpg" width="310" height="363" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="2.jpg" style="opacity: 1;">
 </li>
 <li>
    <img  width="310" height="363" src="3.jpg">
 </li>      
</ul>
```

Here is my code snippet.

```
$img = $xpath->query("//ul[@id='product-slider']//img/@src");
foreach($img as $i){
  echo $i->nodeValue;
}
```

It does not find the src of all image except first.
Can somebody provide some help?

Have a look at this http://codepad.viper-7.com/RiiFfK

Comment: Instead of  $i->nodeValue; use  $i->getAttribute('src');

Answer (score 2):

To get a list of all images (actually, all the values from the `src` attributes) inside this `ul`, in your case, you can use XPath Axes:

```
//ul[@id='product-slider']/descendant::img/@src
```

What this does is:

1. `/ul[@id='product-slider']` selects the `ul` element with `id='product-seller'`
2. `/descendant::img` selects all the descendants (children, grandchildren, etc.) from the `ul`
3. `/@src` selects the `src` attribute of each one of these descendants.

XPath Axes is a great tool, you can find more information about it in here: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp (I know they're not the most relliable source for everything, but this XPath tutorial is quite a good intro).

**Edit:** Using OP's new code snippet from codepad as an example:
The captured element inside the source code from [Snapdeal Link](http://www.snapdeal.com/product/apple-iphone-5s-16-gb/1302850866#bcrumbLabelId:175) is **the following `ul`, in which only the first `img` tag contains a `src` attribute.**

```html
 <ul id="product-slider" class="mainImageSlider">
  <li>
   <img title="Apple iPhone 5S 16 GB (Gold)"  class="jqzoom zoomPad lazyBg" itemprop="image"  src="http://n2.sdlcdn.com/imgs/a/j/x/large/Apple-iPhone-5S-16-GB-SDL218153659-1-d5617.jpg" width="310" height="363" alt="Apple iPhone 5S 16 GB (Gold)" bigimage="http://n4.sdlcdn.com/imgs/a/j/x/Apple-iPhone-5S-16-GB-SDL218153659-1-d5617.jpg">
  </li>
  <li>
   <img title="Apple iPhone 5S 16 GB (Gold)"  class="jqzoom zoomPad lazyBg"  lazySrc="http://n1.sdlcdn.com/imgs/a/j/x/large/Apple-iPhone-5S-16-GB-SDL218153659-2-af89e.jpg" width="310" height="363" alt="Apple iPhone 5S 16 GB (Gold)" bigimage="http://n1.sdlcdn.com/imgs/a/j/x/Apple-iPhone-5S-16-GB-SDL218153659-2-af89e.jpg">
  </li>
  <li>
   <img title="Apple iPhone 5S 16 GB (Gold)"  class="jqzoom zoomPad lazyBg"  lazySrc="http://n4.sdlcdn.com/imgs/a/p/0/large/Apple-iPhone-5S-16-GB-SDL218153659-3-14019.jpg" width="310" height="363" alt="Apple iPhone 5S 16 GB (Gold)" bigimage="http://n4.sdlcdn.com/imgs/a/p/0/Apple-iPhone-5S-16-GB-SDL218153659-3-14019.jpg">
  </li>
  <li>
   <img title="Apple iPhone 5S 16 GB (Gold)"  class="jqzoom zoomPad lazyBg"  lazySrc="http://n4.sdlcdn.com/imgs/a/p/0/large/Apple-iPhone-5S-16-GB-SDL218153659-4-fa8f3.jpg" width="310" height="363" alt="Apple iPhone 5S 16 GB (Gold)" bigimage="http://n4.sdlcdn.com/imgs/a/p/0/Apple-iPhone-5S-16-GB-SDL218153659-4-fa8f3.jpg">
  </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the above explanation. However it still returns only src of one image. @bruno
Please have a look at this [link](http://codepad.viper-7.com/RiiFfK)

Comment: @Shubham If you check the source code of your target `ul` on snapdeal, you will see only the first `img` contains a `src` attribute; all the others contains a `lazySrc` attribute instead. If you try the same XPath above with `@bigimage`, for instance, you'll get 4 urls.

Comment: all the four <img /> tag contains src attribute @bruno

Comment: It doesn't. I just updated the answer, please check. Btw, it's better if you use `id` instead of `class` to match XPath expressions: their uniqueness is more reliable.